# Nokia Asha QA faild with summary The application cannot launch successfully in 25s.

Tags: nokia

Sir/Ma'am,

I am newer in nokia asha development. I have developed an application using LWUIT for Asha Software Platform 1.0 and Asha Software Platform 1.1.1. Every thing working fine while testing on my own device and emulator. After app submission they declined the application and showing QA report like that.

Failed QA.
SUMMARY: The application cannot launch successfully in 25s.
STEPS TO REPRODUCE:
1. Download and install the content.
2. Launch the application.
ACTUAL RESULT: The application cannot launch successfully in 25s.
EXPECTED RESULT: The application can be launched normally.
AFFECTED DEVICES: Asha Software Platform 1.0 and Asha Software Platform 1.1.1.
FREQUENCY REPRODUCED: 100%.

Can any one please help me how to resolve this problem.
Thanks and regards
Wahid

Answer (score 1):

You found a typical problem with app stores:
The testers try work very efficient. So they only give yes/no information. When something is failed, or the tester thinks it is failed, you just get information that it is failed. Nothing more. You get only standard text.

What you can try to do: 
1) you can use remote device access to test you app with other devices in a test center. 
http://developer.nokia.com/resources/remote-device-access

2) ask publish support for more information how your app fails. (does is starts at all?)
http://developer.nokia.com/publish/support

Comment: Thanks a lot Meier. i went through your suggestion and got the positive feedback from the nokia support people let see what they will do regarding that.